# Conditions for 2 columns in DF to get the 3 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I would like to make an IF condition to set the value in a new column ('new_col'). General idea is like:

if 'Score' = np.nan & 'Year' = 2012: return 1

elif 'Score' == np.nan & 'Year' = 2013: return 2

else: return 'Score'

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014], 'Score': [10, 15, np.nan, np.nan, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year', 'Score'])



  year  Score
0  2010   10.0
1  2011   15.0
2  2012    1.0
3  2013    2.0
4  2014    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First for test missing values is necessary use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), then is possible compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` and set values by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['Score'].isna() & df['year'].eq(2012)
m2 = df['Score'].isna() & df['year'].eq(2013)

df['Score'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], default=df['Score'])
print (df)
   year  Score
0  2010   10.0
1  2011   15.0
2  2012    1.0
3  2013    2.0
4  2014    3.0
```

For new column use:

```
df['new_col'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], default=df['Score'])
print (df)
   year  Score  new_col
0  2010   10.0     10.0
1  2011   15.0     15.0
2  2012    NaN      1.0
3  2013    NaN      2.0
4  2014    3.0      3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [`Series.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
condition_1 = (df['Score'].isnull()) & (df['year'] == 2012)
condition_2 = (df['Score'].isnull()) & (df['year'] == 2013)
values = [1, 2]

df['new_col'] = np.select([condition_1, condition_2], values, df['Score'])
```

The syntax of `np.select` is : `numpy.select(condition_list, choice_list, default_value)`

```
df

    year    Score   new_col
0   2010    10.0    10.0
1   2011    15.0    15.0
2   2012    NaN     1.0
3   2013    NaN     2.0
4   2014    3.0     3.0
```